# How to require a header-only library without binary in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I created a header-only library, which is installed with cmake using

```
add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
```

and exported targets.
This works fine, when I use `find_package(mylib REQUIRED)` and `target_link_library` in the cmake file of another library (`mylib2`), which includes the headers.

But when I link against `mylib2` using exported targets and `target_link_library`, the generated VS files contain `mylib.lib` in the link libraries.

When I look for the string `mylib.lib` in the generated files of all three projects, only the visual studio files contain this, none of the `PackageConfig` or `PackageTargets` files contain the filename.

The header-library uses exported targets this in its CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(mylib INTERFACE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES)
target_link_libraries(mylib INTERFACE somelibraries)
target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)
configure_package_config_file(mylibConfig.cmake.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(TARGETS mylib EXPORT mylib-targets)
install(EXPORT mylib-targets FILE mylibTargets.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(DIRECTORY ./ DESTINATION include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

The second library just uses

```
find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
add_library(mylib2 source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mylib2 mylib)
# some stuff to export targets, similar to the first lib
```

And the final project uses

```
add_binary(myproject source.cpp)
set(LINK_LIBRARIES mylib2)
target_link_libraries(myproject ${LINK_LIBRARIES}) # mylib2.lib is added to the project.

add_binary(myproject2 source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myproject mylib2) # only the include paths are added.
```

The problem only happens when the libraries are set from a variable.

At which point of the process does cmake add the library filename to the link-libraries? Shouldn't it inherit the `INTERFACE` property?

Comment: You don't install `mylib2` target in the first code snippet, so you cannot use it from the second code. That is, you may use `mylib2`, but it denotes a *library name* (which is transformed into `mylib2.lib`), not a *target*.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made a mistake when simplifying the code to post it here. The header library is ``mylib`` and only defines its own targets (and exports the ``mylib`` target). The second library (``mylib2``) "links" against the ``mylib`` exported target and gets the correct include path from it. The program-project links against ``mylib2``, but not explicitly against ``mylib``, but adds ``mylib.lib`` to the library list. I rearranged the code snippets in the question and fixed the wrong reference to ``mylib2``.

Answer (score -1):

To include a library, you usually have to **include** header files and link some object files.

With that said, if said library is header-only, you only need to perform `include_directories(<library-include-folder>)` and you're set to go. Since normally your library shouldn't be compiled into an .lib file.

In your case you probably have to do: (assuming mylib is header-only)

```
find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
# Provides MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR to include
# The line above also provides a MYLIB_LIBRARIES, which for header-only libraries should be empty

include_directories(${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${MYLIB_LIBRARIES}) # This can be onmitted since there is nothing to link
```

Comment: I packaged it using [exported targets](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/), which set the target includes, compile defines, etc. correctly, when you just add the library to ``target_link_libraries``. It seems a bit strange to use ``target_link_libraries`` for a header-only library, but it works nicely when linking ``mylib2``.

Comment: If the targets are configured correctly, the `include_directories` should not be needed at all, so this answer is not really relevant to the question in my opinion.